# Sort the output in Hadoop Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am a beginner using Hadoop and I want to read a text file through MapReduce and output it. I have set up a counter to see the order of the data, but the output is not in order. Here are my code and screenshot.

Question: How can we sort the output based on the value of the key?

Sample input data in text file:

199907 21 22 23 24 25

199808 26 27 28 29 30

199909 31 32 33 34 35

200010 36 37 38 39 40

200411 41 42 43 44 45

Mapper

```
public static class TestMapper
        extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{
    int days = 1;
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        /* get the file name */
        FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
        String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
        //context.write(new Text(filename), new Text(""));

        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        String yearMonth = token.nextToken();

        if(Integer.parseInt(yearMonth) ==0)
            return;

        while(token.hasMoreTokens()){
            context.write(new Text(yearMonth+" "+days),new Text(token.nextToken()));
        }
        days++; 
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
public static class TestReducer
        extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ArrayList<String> valList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Text val: values)
            valList.add(val.toString());
        context.write(key,new Text(valList.toString()));
    }
}
```

Driver/Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length < 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: Class name <in> [<in>...] <out>");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "My Class");

    
    job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/myPath"));
    job.setJarByClass(myJar.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TestMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(TestReducer.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
    for (int i = 0; i < otherArgs.length - 1; ++i) {
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[i]));
    }
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[otherArgs.length - 1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Screenshot part of the output

[image]

Comment: Please put the `Driver` or main class of your `mapreduce` job

Comment: @Tashkhisi Thanks for your remind, I've made the update.

Comment: Please also put sample input for your program

Comment: @Tashkhisi following is the sample input text file. 
[link](https://www.file.io/download/NdK4PvRMHqkr)

Comment: I can't download the file. please put some line of your input in the question.

Comment: @Tashkhisi 
[sample data](https://textuploader.com/182r5)
The original document will be displayed until 2013

Comment: Here is the output according to your input https://textuploader.com/1829a which is sorted very well! what is the problem?

Comment: @Tashkhisi
I'm sorry I'm not very good at describing the problem I'm currently encountering.
Here is the full input: (https://products.groupdocs.app/viewer/view?file=43651aa3-4f6a-45e6-9ad1-d9ffc2dbd734/Sample%20in.txt)
This is my result (without the counter): (https://products.groupdocs.app/viewer/view?file=1af833b8-db3d-4f44-9c9b-53aa3baa6dc8/myOutput.txt)
It seems like my result have been split into four with the wrong order.
Commands I've typed. 
1. hadoop jar jarfile.jar jarfile.class input.txt output_dir
2. hadoop fs -cat output_dir/* > myoutput.txt